# How do I avoid a numeric data overflow

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that ran fine in our old MySQL database where there is a check:

```
WHERE column_x + column_y > 524288000
```

Now that we've migrated to Redshift, the query fails:

```
ERROR: Numeric data overflow (addition)
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Numeric data overflow (addition)
  code:      1058
  context:   
  query:     915381
  location:  numeric.hpp:112
  process:   query4_s0_22 [pid=6421]
  ----------------------------------------------- [SQL State=XX000]
```

Both columns are of type `bigint`. When running the query without adding the columns (just checking against one column or the other) the query executes fine. I'm assuming there are rows where `column_x + column_y` is greater than the max size of `bigint`.

What's the workaround here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE column_x::numeric(20) + column_y::numeric(20) > 524288000
```

Comment: Thanks, it still overflowed, but then I tried explicitly setting the size and it worked nicely. Once my edit is accepted or some other clarification is made I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Dean Your edit was not accepted but I edited it. Does it work like that?

Answer (score 2):

Simply change addition into subtraction:

```
WHERE column_x > 524288000 - column_y
```

Comment: That's a clever solution that will work for me. Although I should mention that there's a potential failure case if column_y can have massive negative values.

Answer (score 1):

multiple by 1/x :) before comparing (divide will make it fail on 0):

```
WHERE column_x * (1/X) + column_y* (1/X) > 524288000* (1/X)
```

Comment: 2 should do as your only adding two columns